# Make scrollable elements of varying sizes scroll at once and meet evenly using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three column classes of varying heights that I want to meet evenly once scrolled to the bottom by having each scroll at different speeds.  Something like this

https://forum.bubble.io/t/synchronized-scrolling-multiple-columns-scroll-at-different-speeds/161938/2

The larger columns should scroll slower in order to meet evenly once scrolled down all the way.
The columns are filled with images using other javascript code I wrote.

The method I've tried using event listeners is extremely slow and unreliable since the events start to nest and interrupt one another.  How else could I approach this?

```
.column{
    overflow: auto;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #468189;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.portfolio-grid{
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
}

<div class="portfolio-grid">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>

var columns = document.getElementsByClassName("column");

columns[0].addEventListener("scroll", myfunction);
columns[1].addEventListener("scroll", myfunction2);
columns[2].addEventListener("scroll", myfunction3);

function myfunction(){
    columns[1].removeEventListener("scroll", myfunction2);
    columns[2].removeEventListener("scroll", myfunction3);
    columns[1].scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
    columns[2].scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
    columns[1].addEventListener("scroll", myfunction2);
    columns[2].addEventListener("scroll", myfunction3);
}

function myfunction2(){
    columns[0].removeEventListener("scroll", myfunction2);
    columns[2].removeEventListener("scroll", myfunction3);
    columns[0].scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
    columns[2].scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
    columns[0].addEventListener("scroll", myfunction);
    columns[2].addEventListener("scroll", myfunction3);
}

function myfunction3(){
    columns[0].removeEventListener("scroll", myfunction2);
    columns[1].removeEventListener("scroll", myfunction3);
    columns[0].scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
    columns[1].scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
    columns[0].addEventListener("scroll", myfunction);
    columns[1].addEventListener("scroll", myfunction2);
}
```

Comment: add a code with sample run option

Answer (score 1):

The `scroll` event fires repeatedly and asynchronously. In your code, you disable the listener, set the `scrollTop` of the other elements and recover the listener. What actually happens is that the `scrollTop` is scheduled and handled by the system, whereas the listener is recovered synchronously. This means that, by the time the `scrollTop` is done, the event handler is already working.

Aside from other problems, you may want to read about [event throttling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event#scroll_event_throttling). A working example, which can be improved:

```js
const els = document.getElementsByClassName('column');
let factors = [];
let hfuncts = [];
let ticking = false;
let ttimer;
let ffactor = els[0].scrollHeight;
function recoverScroll(i){
  if (ticking === false){
    for (let j = 0; j < els.length; j++){
      if (j !== i){
        els[j].addEventListener('scroll', hfuncts[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    if (ttimer){
      clearTimeout(ttimer);
    }
    ticking = false;
    ttimer = setTimeout(() => {recoverScroll(i)}, 300)
  }
}
function handleScroll(i){
  ticking = true;
  for (let j = 0; j < els.length; j++){
    if (j !== i){
      els[j].removeEventListener('scroll', hfuncts[j]);
      let tpos = els[i].scrollTop * factors[j] / factors[i];
      els[j].scrollTo(0, tpos);
    }
  }
  recoverScroll(i);
}
for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++){  
  factors.push((els[i].scrollHeight - els[i].clientHeight) / ffactor);  
}
for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
  let cf = function(){handleScroll(i)};
  hfuncts.push(cf);
  els[i].addEventListener('scroll', cf);
}
```

```css
.column{
    overflow: auto;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #468189;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.portfolio-grid{
    overflow: auto;
    height: 200px;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-grid">
    <div class="column"><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p></div>
    <div class="column"><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p></div>
    <div class="column"><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p><p>Text</p></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the key is that `recoverScroll` only works about 300 ms after the last scroll event has been fired. This delay needs to be chosen carefully. Too short and you get the same problem as before. Too long and the user can scroll a different element and not get the effect. Unfortunately, this depends on how each system chooses to do the scroll event. This event is notoriously difficult to intercept.